# Query won't insert but no errors

Tags: php, mysql

What i'm trying to accomplish with my code is that it first checks if the code is right and then it has to insert the query. But somehow it won't insert... and i don't know what i did wrong on the first sight.

My PHP:

```
include 'functions/conn.php';
$Giveaway = "SELECT `content` FROM `sub_codes` WHERE `current_uses` > '0'";
$result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $Giveaway);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1);
    if ($_POST['Code']===$row) {
        $sql3 = "SELECT `user_id` FROM `users` ORDER BY `user_id` DESC LIMIT 1";
        $result3 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql3);
        $row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($result3);
        $_start_date = date('Y-m-d');
        $_end_date = $row2;
        $sql2 = "SELECT `end_date` FROM `sub_codes` WHERE `content` = '".$_POST['Code']."'";
        $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
        $row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `partner_subscriptions` SET `user_id` = '$row3' + 1, `sub_id` = '99', `allowed_users` = '100', `start_date` = '$_start_date', `end_date` = '$row2';";
        if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            echo "New record created successfully";
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
        }
} else {
    echo "Wrong code";
}
```

And my html:

```
<br/><div class="form-group">
  <label title="Required">Free description code:</label>
    <input type="Code" name="Code" class="form-control" id="Code"
      required="true"/>
    </div><br/>
```

This is what i tried so far. If you need more code ask me. But I think this is enough. I don't get any errors.

**EDIT**

this is the remaining code of my insert page

```
<?php

//Controleer of de e-mail nog niet gebruikt is.
if (usedmail($_POST['username'])==true) {
$lastID = saveUser($_POST['fnln'], $_POST['username'], 
password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT), 0, 0, 1);
$niv = NULL;
if ($_POST['type'] == "3") { // If the partner is an educational 
institution look for niveau
    $niv = NivID($_POST['niv']);
}

$path = saveImage();
Contact($lastID);
Image($lastID);
Social($lastID);
Story($lastID);
Skill($lastID);
$orgID = saveOrganisation($lastID, $_POST['organisation'], $path, $_POST['type'], $_POST['branche'], $niv);
updateUser($orgID, $lastID);
}
else {
header('Location: ../../mailerror');
}
function saveUser($fnln, $userName, $passWord, $orgID, $partID) {
require '../conn.php';
$sql = "INSERT INTO `users` (`user_id`, `fnln`, `username`, `password`, 
`org_id`, `part_id`, `type`, `active`) VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$_fnln = $fnln;
$_username = $userName;
$_password = $passWord;
$_orgID = $orgID;
$_partID = $partID;
$_type = '1';
$_active = '1';
$stmt->bind_param("sssiiii", $_fnln, $_username, $_password, $_orgID, $_partID, $_type, $_active);
$stmt->execute();
$lastID = $conn->insert_id;
$stmt->close();
return $lastID;

}

function saveImage()
{
$image = $_FILES['frontImage']['tmp_name'][0];
$random = substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYS", 10)), 0, 10);
$pic = $random . $_FILES['frontImage']['name'][0];
$url = "../../assets/img/profile/" . $pic;
$uploadURL = uploadImage($image, $url, 70);
return $uploadURL;
}

function uploadImage($src, $dest, $quality)
{
$info = getimagesize($src);

if ($info['mime'] == 'image/jpeg') {
    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
} elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/gif') {
    $image = imagecreatefromgif($src);
} elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/png') {
    $image = imagecreatefrompng($src);
} else {
    die('Unknown image file format. Please upload a jpg, jpeg, gif or a png file.');
}

imagejpeg($image, $dest, $quality);

//  $dest = str_replace("../", "", $dest);
$dest = str_replace(".assets/img/", "", $dest);

return $dest;
}

function NivID($name) {
require '../conn.php';
$content = strtoupper($name);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM niveau WHERE `name`='".$content."'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    return $row['id'];
}
else { // Add niv to db if it's unkown
    $sqlNiv = "INSERT INTO `niveau` (`id`, `name`) VALUES (NULL, ?);";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sqlNiv);
    $_name = strtoupper($name);
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $_name);
    $stmt->execute();
    $nivid = $conn->insert_id;
    $stmt->close();
    return $nivid;
 }
}

//Add Contactrow
function Contact($id){
require '../conn.php';
$sqlContact = "INSERT INTO `user_contact` (`contact_id`, `user_id`, 
`telnr`, `mobilenr`, `age`, `sex`, `city`) VALUES (NULL, '" . $id . "', 
NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);";
if ($conn->query($sqlContact) === TRUE) {
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
 }
}

 //Add Imagerow
function Image($id){
require '../conn.php';
$sqlImage = " INSERT INTO `user_image` (`image_id`, `user_id`, `path`) VALUES (NULL, '" . $id . "', '');";
if ($conn->query($sqlImage) === TRUE) {
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}
}

//Add Socialrow
function Social($id){
require '../conn.php';
$sqlSocial = " INSERT INTO `user_social` (`social_id`, `user_id`, 
`facebook`, `linkedin`, `twitter`, `instagram`, `youtube`, `website`) VALUES 
(NULL, '" . $id . "', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);";
if ($conn->query($sqlSocial) === TRUE) {
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}
}

 //Add Storyrow
function Story($id){
require '../conn.php';
$sqlStory = " INSERT INTO `user_story` (`story_id`, `user_id`, `story`) VALUES (NULL, '" . $id . "', '');";
if ($conn->query($sqlStory) === TRUE) {
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}
}

//Add Skillrow
function Skill($id){
require '../conn.php';
$sqlSkill = " INSERT INTO `item_skill_label` (`skill_label_id`, `user_id`, `label_5`, `label_6`, `label_7`) VALUES (NULL , '" . $id . "', '', '', '');";
if ($conn->query($sqlSkill) === TRUE) {
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}
}

 function saveOrganisation($userID, $name, $path, $type, $branche, $niv)
{
require '../conn.php';
$sql = "INSERT INTO `organisations` (`org_id`, `user_id`, `name`, `path`, `type`, `branche`, `niveau`) VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$_userID = $userID;
$_name = $name;
$_path = $path;
$_type = $type;
$_branche = $branche;
$_niv = $niv;
$stmt->bind_param("issiii", $_userID, $_name, $_path, $_type, $_branche, $_niv);
$stmt->execute();
$lastID = $conn->insert_id;
$stmt->close();
return $lastID;
}



function updateUser($orgID, $lastID)
{
require '../conn.php';
$sql = "UPDATE `users` SET `org_id` = '" . $orgID . "' WHERE `user_id` = '" . $lastID . "';";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    header('Location: ../../login');
    die();
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
}


//Check of het emailadres al in gebruik is
function usedmail($mail){
require '../conn.php';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username`='" . $mail . "';";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    return false;
}
else{
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: check whether auto-commit is true or false?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: quick issue I can see is SET user id = `'$row3'` and other variables will be entered as string literals.

Comment: `$sql = "INSERT INTO `partner_subscriptions` SET `user_id` = '$row3' + 1, `sub_id` = '99', `allowed_users` = '100', `start_date` = '$_start_date', `end_date` = '$row2';";` print this sql and check whether it has all values correctly.

Comment: @comphonia i did because otherwise i can't take the last `user_id`

Comment: Yes, you can use it that way but `$a=5; echo '$a'; ` will print $a not 5

Comment: Also, I'd suggest you switch to PDO using prepared statements early if you're just starting out.

Comment: @Ash-b sorry but what is the best way to check the query?

Comment: What *do* you get? A blank page or the message that it got successfully inserted?

Comment: @Solarflare that is successfully is inserted

Comment: `echo $sql;die;` it will print the query.

Comment: @Ash-b i can't see anything because if i put it outside the if statement i get an error and if it is in the if statement i can't see it because the page will be redirected to the inlog page\

Comment: post db connection string in conn.php

Comment: tell me one more thing , so that i can post the answer, why are you setting `user_id`  as `'$row3' + 1` ?

Comment: @Ash-b well because in the same time it will make a user in another table and i have to take that user_id and i didn't know how so this was the most easy solution

Comment: @snfrox my connection is ok because in the same time it will add a new user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
include 'functions/conn.php';
$Giveaway = "SELECT `content` FROM `sub_codes` WHERE `current_uses` > '0'";
$result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $Giveaway);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1);

  //here $row is an array , you have to use $row['content']
  if ($_POST['Code']===$row['content']) {

      $sql3 = "SELECT `user_id` FROM `users` ORDER BY `user_id` DESC LIMIT 1";
      $result3 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql3);
      $row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($result3);
      $_start_date = date('Y-m-d');

      //$_end_date = $row2;
      //$row is not yet defined so move this line after $row2;

      $sql2 = "SELECT `end_date` FROM `sub_codes` WHERE `content` = '".$_POST['Code']."'";
      $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
      $row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2);

      //again $row2 is an array use $row2['end_date']
      $_end_date = $row2['end_date'];
      $user_id = $row3['user_id'] + 1;
      $sql = "INSERT INTO `partner_subscriptions` SET `user_id` = $user_id, `sub_id` = '99', `allowed_users` = '100', `start_date` = '$_start_date', `end_date` = '$_end_date';";

      if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
          echo "New record created successfully";
      } else {
          echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
      }
 else {
  echo "Wrong code";
 }
```

read all the comments , it should work.

Comment: i get an error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting '-' or identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\new-sc\partner.php on line 28` its the line of the last query

Comment: it doesn't work but i will post my function file with all the inserts for that page

Comment: what error you are getting? is it not inserting in `partner_subscriptions` table?

Comment: I don't get anything... because it wil automaticly go to the inlog page. I added my remaining code so you see the other inserts of the page

Answer (score 0):

$row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2); // will result an array i hope
Please verify `end_date` = '$row2'; part in the insert query.. so as exact date(or date format) is passed